# 文字列結合した際に、文字Kが文字aを消してしまう

Tags: java, アルゴリズム, array, データ構造

現在、leetcodeの1768. Merge Strings Alternatelyを解いています。
下記が問題文(*1)と例題(*2)です
事象は、文字列結合した際に、文字Kが文字aを消してしまうことです。
コードは'(*3)にあります。
この原因と改善方法について教えていただけると幸いです。

*1

> 2 つの文字列 word1 と word2 が与えられます。 word1 から始めて交互に文字を追加して、文字列を結合します。ある文字列が他の文字列より長い場合は、マージされた文字列の末尾に追加の文字を追加します。
>
> マージされた文字列を返します。

*2
Example 1:

```
Input: word1 = "abc", word2 = "pqr"
Output: "apbqcr"
Explanation: The merged string will be merged as so:
word1:  a   b   c
word2:    p   q   r
merged: a p b q c r
```

*3

```java
class Solution {
    public String mergeAlternately(String word1, String word2) {
        int len = word1.length() + word2.length();
        int count =0;
        char [] c1 =  word1.toCharArray();
        char [] c2 =  word2.toCharArray();
        String merge=""; 
         char tmp1 = 'A';
         char tmp2 = 'A';
         int count1=0;
         int count2=0;
        for (char c3 : c1){
            merge+=c3;          
            merge+=tmp1;
             tmp1++;
            count1++;         
        }
        System.out.println(merge);
    
        for (char c4:c2){
            merge = merge.replace(tmp2, c4);
            tmp2++;
            count2++;
        }
 System.out.println(merge);
        if(count1 < count2){
            for (int i=count1; i < word2.length();i++)
            merge += word2.charAt(i);
        } else{
        merge =  merge.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
            if(merge.length() != len){
                merge = merge.substring(0, merge.length()-1);
            }
        }
    return merge;
    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

`char tmp2 = 'A';`で初期化した`tmp2`に対して、26回以上`tmp2++;`を繰り返したらどうなるでしょうか。
実際に試すと分かりますが、'Z'の次は'[','\',...'`'と変わっていき、32回目で'a'になります。

問題の入力例だと`word2`が33文字なので、`merge = merge.replace(tmp2, c4);`が`merge = merge.replace('a', 'x');`となり、'a'が'x'に上書きされて、このような結果になります。

そもそも、現状のやり方だと、33文字以上の入力がある場合に破綻してしまうので、やり方自体を見直さないと修正はできません。